# Use elasticsearch in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearch using composer. This is my AppKernel.php file

```
new Elasticsearch\Client()
```

This is my TestController.php file.

```
    <?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller; 

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Elasticsearch\Client;
//use Elasticsearch\Common\AbstractFactory;

class TestController extends Controller{

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="test-homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(){
        $client = new Elasticsearch\Client();
        dump($client);
        die;
    }
}
```

I am using eclipse as my ide and it shows me error like elasticsearch\Client cannot be resolved.Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: If you define `use` statement then you don't need FQCN. BTW your FQCN is not right it should starts with `\` to prevent loading class from current namespace.

Then: in `AppKernel.php` you need to define bundles, not every library you installed.

If you have small experience in PHP try to use more easy-to-study frameworks. Symfony is mostly for experienced developers.

If you think that you can work with Symfony then I would recommend you bundle for integrating ElasticSearch and Elastica: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle. It will save your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to instanciate the imported class, using the short name (base on the use statements on your class), like this :

```
$client = new Client();
```

Or with the FQCN :

```
$client = new \Elasticsearch\Client();
```

(note that the new statement begin with a \ which prevent from trying to load the class from the current namespace (ie : AppBundle\Controller : \AppBundle\Controller\Elasticsearch\Client)